# Converting int to C++11 scoped enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

I would like to convert an `int` to a C++11 scoped enum value. For example, I may read in integer values from a database or XML file and convert these to scoped enum values within my C++ application.

What is the best way to deal with integer values that are not defined within the scoped enum?

Consider the following code, which runs on VS2013.

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Fruit : int { Apple=0, Pear=1, Orange=2 };

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int n=3;
    Fruit fruit = static_cast<Fruit>(n);
    std::cout << "The value of n is: " << static_cast<int>(fruit) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:
`The value of n is: 3`

However, 3 is not a predefined constant value of `Fruit`. Is the above code correct C++11?

Comment: The code is correct C++11. What do you want to happen when the integer value is outside the range?

Comment: If the integer value is out of range I would raise an error.